# Reference request: Solution to second order parabolic linear BVP belongs to $\mathcal{C}(0,T;H^1(\Omega))$

Tags: reference-request, parabolic-pde, linear-pde, regularity, continuity

I am currently reading the paper [1]. In Theorem 3.1. b) the following boundary-value problem is given:
\begin{align*}
    \partial_{t} y  - \Delta y + g\cdot y = f \text{ in } ]0,T[ \times \Omega\\
    \nabla y \cdot n = 0 \text{ in } ]0,T[ \times \partial \Omega\\
    y(0) = y_0 \text{ in } \Omega
\end{align*}

with $f \in L^2(Q), g \in L^{\infty}(Q)$, $y_0 \in H^1(\Omega)$.
The authors then state that there exists a solution $y \in \mathcal{C}(0,T;V)$ such that:
\begin{equation*}
\lVert y \rVert_{\mathcal{C}(0,T;H^1)} \leq C \cdot (\lVert f \rVert_{L^2(Q)} + \lVert y_0 \rVert_{H^1(\Omega)})
\end{equation*}

is there some reference to this ? I can't get this to work just using the Galerkin approximation.
Thanks in advance !

**Reference**

[1] Malte Braack, Martin F. Quaas, Benjamin Tews, Boris Vexler, "Optimization of fishing strategies in space and time as a non-convex optimal control problem", (English) Journal of Optimization Theory and Applications 178, No. 3, 950-972 (2018), [DOI:10.1007/s10957-018-1304-7](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10957-018-1304-7), [MR3836262](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3836262), [Zbl 1409.49018](https://zbmath.org/1409.49018).

Comment: As usual, it is not so easy to find readable references for parabolic equations. Krylov's book "Lectures on Elliptic and parabolic equations in Sobolev spaces" contains all ingredients to write dowon a proof... but deals only with parabolic equations in the whole space. The classical book by Ladyzenskaja-Solonnikov-Uralceva contains much more...the same for the book by Liebermann, if you are able to find the results (sometimes I do not find even the results I can prove). If you know the results when $g=0$ and full estimates in $W^{1,2}$, then the results follows from the method of continuity.

Comment: I am sorry I cannot give a reference...I could explain how to prove it, but discussing. Maybe somebody else knows an easy reference.

Comment: I don't get why AMS does not release the (very important) book by Ladyzenskaja-Solonnikov-Uralceva with modern LaTex typography. This book is so hard to read.

Comment: @akira You are right, I find unreadable mainly the fonts.

Comment: It seems Dautray-Lions Vol. 5, Chap. XV, §1 also contains results very close to what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also do not know an easy and direct reference, in particular since there are homogeneous Neumann boundary conditions which are usually not treated in examples.

Anyway, here is a blueprint how one *could* argue, but I am not claiming that this is the minimal or most direct/elegant way. I am just giving a possible blueprint based on a nonautonomous perturbation result of maximal parabolic regularity as in [ACFP]. (See also there for notions and further references.)

- On a sufficiently smooth or convex domain $\Omega$, the domain of the (negative) Neumann Laplacian $-\Delta_N$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ is $H^2(\Omega)$. It also satisfies maximal parabolic regularity on $L^2(\Omega)$ since its negative generates an analytic semigroup.
- From [ACFP Proposition 1.3] it follows that the operator family $A(t) := -\Delta_N + g(t)$ still satisfies (now: nonautonomous) maximal parabolic regularity on $L^2(\Omega)$ with domain $H^2(\Omega)$.
- Thus, for every $f \in L^2(Q)$ and every $y_0 \in (L^2(\Omega),H^2(\Omega))_{1/2,2}$, the equation in OP has a unique solution $u \in \mathcal W := W^{1,2}(0,T;L^2(\Omega) \cap L^2(0,T;H^2(\Omega))$ with $$\|u\|_{\mathcal W} \lesssim \|f\|_{L^2(Q)} + \|y_0\|_{(L^2(\Omega),H^2(\Omega))_{1/2,2}}.$$
- It remains to identify $(L^2(\Omega),H^2(\Omega))_{1/2,2} = H^1(\Omega)$, e.g. by considering a continuous linear extension operator which takes the function spaces in question to their $\mathbb{R}^n$ version where the result is a standard one, and to recall the embedding $$\mathcal W \hookrightarrow C\bigl([0,T];(L^2(\Omega),H^2(\Omega))_{1/2,2}\bigr) = C([0,T];H^1(\Omega)).$$

In fact, I think that one could dispose of most, if not all, regularity assumptions on $\Omega$ by arguing in a more sharp manner, since the $H^2(\Omega)$ regularity is not explicitly asked for, but this seems not to be the focus of the question.

**[ACFP]** *Arendt, Wolfgang; Chill, Ralph; Fornaro, Simona; Poupaud, César*, [**$L^{p}$-maximal regularity for nonautonomous evolution equations**](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jde.2007.02.010), J. Differ. Equations 237, No. 1, 1-26 (2007). [ZBL1126.34037](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1126.34037).